# Properly subclass UIView in Swift linked to XIB file

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have been wondering how to properly subclass UIView in Swift with a linked XIB file. Basically, I want a Swift file with methods for my subclass of UIView with an interface builder XIB file for the view itself. I want to give names to the components of my XIB file and access them in instances of my UIView subclass. I am not sure if I am doing this properly now, below is my UIView subclass for ChapterView, which includes a single UITextView named chapterText:

```
class ChapterView: UIView {

    var viewFromNib: UIView?
    @IBOutlet weak var chapterText: UITextView!

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        loadSubviews()
    }

    convenience override init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func loadSubviews () {
        self.viewFromNib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ChapterView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
        self.chapterText = viewFromNib?.subviews[0] as UITextView
    }
}
```

I have an XIB file named "ChapterView" with text in the UITextView. In order to add my view to the main view controller's view, I currently have to add ChapterView.viewFromNib when I would like to add the view in the XIB by just adding the instance of ChapterView (eliminating loading the whole view as viewFromNib). What I have is working for me, but it seems ugly. How can I properly do this?

Comment: Personally I would make ChapterView subclass UIViewController instead of UIView. But other than that, what you're doing is perfectly  fine.

Comment: "Ugly" and "properly" are emotive. Stack Overflow is not about emotion. :) Seriously, if it's working, then it's unclear what the question is.

Comment: I guess my only question would be: if ChapterView is always getting its subviews from a nib, then why isn't ChapterView _itself_ the thing that comes from the nib? That is how I would do it. But otherwise what you are doing is perfectly reasonable. Nibs are how you make duplicates of view hierarchies and that is what you are doing.